# GIT: How to avoid duplicated commits while maintaining lots of forks?

Tags: git, format-patch

I have a base repository with a "base site" that I clone to make my clients sites, so I work, make commits, push to the client fork, then I realize that in the middle of my commits there is one or more that must be merge to the base repository. That's what I did:

git format-patch -1 SHA

Then I go to the "base site" repository and do:

git am -3 patch_file

It's ok. The problem is when I want to pull changes from the "base site" to the client repo the commit is duplicated.

Is there a way to avoid that? Maybe a different workflow?

**EDIT:**

In fact I'm still having problems, my explanation isn't so clear. Let me try again:

I have a base repository that contains a 'docs', 'layout', 'pub' and 'sql' folder, there is just a blank 'index.html' in the 'docs' and 'layout' folder. In the 'pub' folder I have Joomla installed.

When I have a new client I make his directory and init a repository, then I add a remote 'base' pointing to the base bare repository, fetch it, checkout base/master and then do 'checkout -b master' to create the master branch from the base's master branch. Then I make a 'clone --bare' in my local server and clone from it in local workstations. We save docs when needed, the designer makes the layout then all of it is commited and pushed to the client's bare repo. We always do a 'rebase origin/master' before pushing, to make sure the local repo is up to date.

So when the layout is done and pushed, I pull it and start to make the Joomla template. So I make a lots of commits, then I realise that I have to make changes in our Joomla components to something to work as it should. Ok, I change a component, commit and continue to making the template, commit, ...

Now I want to bring all the component's commits to the 'base repo' because I want all my clients to have the same changes. When I tried @jleedev solution, all my client's commits went to the top, rewriting it's SHA's that were already in the client's bare repo.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't fully get what you're trying to do, but shouldn't you be using merges, cherry-picks or rebasing instead of patches?

Comment: Cherry-picking still uses patches -- you end up with two commits having the same diff.

Comment: I could use submodules, but it would need 2 repos for each client. The repo with 'docs', 'layout', 'sql', then I would use a Joomla repo (the same for every client) as a submodule in the 'pub' dir, and another submodule in 'pub/templates/client' to the client's html template, right? Is there a way to make the client's html folder be part of the 'top' repo?

Answer (score 3):

Yes! The `git-pull` command performs a fetch followed by a merge. The merge yells at you since you have the same patch expressed as two commits with different names.

If you do `git-pull --rebase`, or the two-step equivalent of `git fetch; git rebase origin/master`, then it will rebase your local changes onto the upstream.

Let's say your repo looks like this; `master` contains the work you've done in client, and `origin/master` represents the upstream base onto which you've applied the emailed patch. After you fetch, you see two divergent branches, but the commit that you've exported is in both lines.

```
~/client-site$ git fetch origin master
```

It looks like this in [GitX](http://gitx.frim.nl/):

[After the fetch http://grab.by/m1T](http://grab.by/m1T)

When you [rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), it takes all your commits on `client` that aren't in `base`, converts them from commits to patches, and applies them one by one onto the upstream head. When it notices that two commits express the same patch, they get smooshed into one (the upstream commit lives and the local one dies).

```
~/client-site$ git rebase origin/master
```

[After the rebase http://grab.by/m1X](http://grab.by/m1X)

As @roe mentions, there are probably better ways to keep your repositories in sync, such as cherry-picking the commit you need and then pushing it. It's quite possible to run into issues when you rebase, but the way you described your workflow of exporting a patch using format-patch and am seems pretty safe.

Comment: Thank you!

So I need to do that before I push my local "client" repo to it's online repo, because the SHA's will change after the rebase right?

Thanks again!

Comment: The idea is to rewrite the client's commit to match the one online, so yes.

Comment: Also, another question: What interface are you using the see the commits? (The one you took screenshots) Thanks!

Comment: But I thought the whole point was that you had some work that you didn't want to push.

Comment: Yes, there is some work that I just want make patches and apply to the "base site" repo, but all my client's local repo is pushed to the client's online repo (I use post-update hook to update the public directory)

Comment: @Fredi: jleedev is using GitX, a gitk-like interface for Mac OS X.